# Any built-in Android function to wrap Canvas drawing?

Tags: android, android-canvas, repeat, android-bitmap

I'm using Canvas to draw on Bitmap.

Consider this is my bitmap (dots are just empty space, x marks the spot):

```
........
......x.
........
........
........
```

If I draw this box:

```
###
###
###
```

starting at `x`, I'd get this:

```
........
......##(#)
......##(#)
......##(#)
........
```

But I want those "leaky" `#`s to be drawn on the far left, as if this bitmap was wrapped. Like Pac-Man.

So basically, what I'd like is some way to instruct Canvas not to draw pixels at (`x, y`) but (`x % width, y % height`). Any simple way to achieve this?

Another example, let's say I want to draw the same 3x3 box/square starting at (width - 1, height - 1), then I want to get this:

```
##.....#
##.....#
........
........
##.....#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the docs there is no built-in function that will let you achieve what you are looking for. Since you are dealing directly with a canvas object the assumption is that the app would handle all of the pixel level drawing information.

Like you mentioned there is more than one way to do it in the app but unfortunately none out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

x=metrics.heightPixels;
y=metrics.widthPixels;
```

And

```
  u=bitmap.getWidth();
  v=bitmap.getHeight();
```

You can figure out easily from these four numbers where the box should be drawn.

In answer to your EDIT:
If part of the square is off the right side of the screen by xx, then draw it on the screen at position xx.
If it is off the left side by xx then draw it at position screenWidth-xx.

If the screen "moves", i.e. you can scroll around the screen, then you will have to do a little bit more.

Comment: I actually want my box to be wrapped around the bitmap, it's not that I can't position it right.

Comment: What do you mean draw the box? Is it a bitmap or are you drawing a rectangle? Either way just use the coords of the bitmap and its dimensions to calculate where the box should go.

Comment: A rectangle. The thing is, I know where it should go, and it should get split. What I'm wondering is: is there any built-in function that will do the job of spliting for me. I'll add another example in my question in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can wrap up the same image. What you can do is insert a second image to the left when the one on right goes off the screen.

So, for example.. Let image be of 4x4 unit. If it goes off the screen(right side) by 1 unit, 3x4 would be visible on right and 1x4(of a new image) would be visible on left. Same way you can work around for top and bottom.